# latest android studio 3.2 preview 11 doesn't generate DataBindingComponent

Tags: android, gradle

When updating to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha11'
```

The DataBindingComponent is not generated

```
:messagingui:javaPreCompileDebug
:messagingui:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/josef/Projects/3hl-android-messaging/messagingui/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug/out/com/schibsted/domain/messaging/ui/databinding/McConversationFragmentBinding.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
import android.databinding.DataBindingComponent;
```